# How can you use Fiddler (or equivalent) with the emulator in the Windows Phone 8 SDK when on a domain/network that uses IPSEC?

Tags: fiddler, hyper-v, ipsec, windows-phone-8

Now that the WP8 Emulator is based on Hyper-V, the old method of using Fiddler to intercept network traffic doesn't work if the network uses IPSEC.

Is there a way to use Fiddler and a WP8 emulator in such a scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the answer at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx

> On a corporate domain, the emulator appears as a separate network device that is not joined to the domain. As a result, **you may also
>   have to get an exception from your IT department** before the emulator
>   can connect to services that are running on the domain-joined
>   development computer.

A network security exception was required.

Answer (score 4):

Fiddler with exactly the same setup as on WP7 (https://fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/phone.asp) works absolutely fine for me.

You grab the traffic from the host system, so the guest (the WP8 emulator) has to bypass that too.

If it doesn't work let me know, but for me and others I know, it runs without any issues.

Comment: This works for the WP7 emulator as ships with the WP8 SDK, but doesn't work with the WP8 emulators. They do not route the traffic in the same way.

Comment: Did you try it ? It's running excactly as I described in front of me.

Comment: yes, of course I tried it. Current thinking is that this may be an IPSEC issue. - Still investigating

Comment: That's possible. I have no IPSec/VPN or IPv6 setup here, but plain IPv4 with unencrypted and SSL/TLS encrypted traffic works as before. But I also heard from (at least) IPv6 users that they had trouble.

Comment: The steps here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2010/10/15/fiddler-and-the-windows-phone-emulator.aspx worked fine for me just now. Screenshot https://twitter.com/ericlaw/status/263709714196611072/photo/1/large

Comment: Have confirmed that this is due to IPSEC restrictions. Updated question to make this clear.

Comment: I'm on a simple home network and am still unable to get fiddler to work with the new emulator.  I'm on win8, stopped the IPSEC service, firewall is off.  I have decrypt https checked and have the cert installed.  The cert installs on the emulator as well, after that the emulator loses connection, strange.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to use something like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) which works at a sub-protocol level and can therefore intercept anything.

Note that analysis won't be nearly as easy as it is in Fiddler though. Also, HTTPS connections might be impossible to analyze because of the whole man-in-the-middle attack prevention brought on by the protocol and certificates and such.

Comment: A protocol analyzer that sees raw packets can't do much with encrypted packets unless it has the keying material to understand them.